# Separating one column into six after loading a .txt file

Tags: r, dataframe

I know this question has probably been asked quite often, but I am still having a lot of trouble with it.

So far what I have is  week1.txt. I am able to load the data into R with

```
week1 = read.csv("week1.txt")
```

but the file is created so that the values for all six columns are in the first column, with each new column that I need being separated by a space. How would I separate the first column into six columns with each new column starting at the space? I have tried and tried but just can't get it.

Comment: Are you actually reading in a CSV file? If there are no commas, it doesn't sound like a comma-separated values file. Did you try `read.table()` instead? You should show a few lines of the file so we know what you're trying to import.

Comment: For future reference, when you post an R question to SO it usually helps if you show us sample data you are trying to input so that we don't have to guess the right answer.

Comment: Ok will do, the question has been answered thank you all for your input :). I will also look into read.table( ) for any future problems with reading files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify space as a separator:

```
week1 = read.csv("week1.txt", sep=" ")
```

The default separator for `read.csv()` is a comma, which wasn't helping to separate the columns in your input file.

Comment: `read.table("week1.txt")` would be more appropriate than using `read.csv` and then overriding its defaults.